# Using non-default preferences in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

Using PreferenceActivity, Android automatically saves simple preferences such as checkboxes being checked etc. I have a couple of questions:

1 - where do these preferences get saved? Is it the same preferences file that PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) returns?

2 - is there a way to use a difference set of preferences? I.e. with context.getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode) you supply a string to identify a particular set of preferences. Is it possible to save preferences from a PreferenceActivity in a set of preferences returned like this?

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Comment: hii do you have answer for it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Have a look at that :
https://idlesun.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-make-preferenceactivity-use-non.html

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
        prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("my_preferences");
        prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

`addPreferencesFromResource()` have to be called after `setSharedPreferencesName()`!

Comment: The danger of links... They have updated the location to http://idlesun.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-make-preferenceactivity-use-non.html -- The link, however, adds only *a little* to the post here... @stephane posted the important code. :)